# Quotation in alias of shell configuration

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh, quotes

I have the following alias in zshrc

```
alias S="nohup startTerminal $(pwd) > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

It works until there are no space characters in the path. How I can modify it that it works with any path?

Comment: Have you tried quoting: `alias S="nohup startTerminal \"$(pwd)\" > /dev/null 2>&1 &"`

Comment: /E/Files/Archive
>>>
[1]  + 239460 done       nohup startTerminal "/E" > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: If that's really `zsh`, there's no need for command substitution: `alias S="nohup startTerminal $PWD > /dev/null 2>&1 &"` should work (no quotes on `$PWD` needed in Z shell's default configuration).

Comment: It is not true. Your alias will be evaluated during configuration load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use a shell `function` rather than `alias` here:

```
S() { nohup startTerminal "$PWD" > /dev/null 2>&1 & }
```